# AttributeError at / 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 138, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 27, in process_response
    if response.get("X-Frame-Options") is not None:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Here is my code,

#views.py

```
class BookList(generic.View):
  model = Book
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    books = Book.objects.all()

    if request.GET.get('Add') == 'Add':
      query = request.GET.get('hidden-book')
      book = Book.objects.filter(pk=query).update(moved=True)
      return book

    context = {'books': books}
    return render(request, 'main.html', context)
```

#main.html

```
<form method="GET" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden-book" value="{{ book.id }}/>
  <input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

#models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
  moved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

When the user presses the 'Add' input button, it should change the moved attribute in book to True. For background, I have an application that has a list of books, each with their own add button, that upon clicking an add button, the book is added to another list of books. My code  works, but when I click the add button an `AttributeError at / 'int' object has no attribute 'get'` is raised. When I go back to 127.0.0.1:8000/, the book has been moved from the first to second list.

Since I don't know what's causing the error, I assumed it was the `query = request.GET.get('hidden-book')` line because it's getting an id which is an int. I tried putting this in a try/except block, but nothing changed. I also tried to change `{{ book.id }}` to {{ book }} to get a string instead, but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the root cause is

```
return book
```

get() needs to return a http response like

```
return render(...)
```

some lines below, not a query object

this should do it:

```
class BookList(generic.View):
  model = Book
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    

    if request.GET.get('Add') == 'Add':
      query = request.GET.get('hidden-book')
      book = Book.objects.filter(pk=query).update(moved=True)
      
    books = Book.objects.all()

    context = {'books': books}
    return render(request, 'main.html', context)
```